# System error 1450 has occurred. Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

Tags: windows, resources, out-of-memory

When i try to access to a network share by typing:

```
net use \\servername\sharename
```

I get the error:

```
System error 1450 has occurred.
Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.
```

If I reboot the system the mount will work fine for a while, then the error appears again.

I've already udpated my system (WIN 2008 R2) to the latest available patch, and I've also followed all the solutions reported here:

[robocopy script : Insufficient system resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738888/robocopy-script-insufficient-system-resources)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to perform the following steps:

1.Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.

2.Locate and then click the following registry subkey:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management

3.On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.

4.In the New Value #1 box, type PoolUsageMaximum, and then press ENTER.

5.Right-click PoolUsageMaximum, and then click Modify.

6.In the Base box, click Decimal, type 60 in the Value data box, and then click OK.

7.If the PagedPoolSize registry entry exists, go to step 8. If the PagedPoolSize registry entry does not exist, create it.

To do this, follow these steps:

•On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
•In the New Value #1 box, type PagedPoolSize, and then press ENTER.

8.Right-click PagedPoolSize, and then click Modify.

9.In the Value data box, type ffffffff, and then click OK.

10.Exit Registry Editor, and then restart the computer.

Comment: Can you explain what this does and why you recommend this? Modifying registry keys like these can have serious impact so advising people to insert seemingly random values without context is a bit risky. I assume you based yourself on this KB https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304101 ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be a number of things. I don't have one specific answer. If this is a VM, get a backup before performing any of the below fixes. Same thing if this is a physical box.

1. It could be a Service running that is consuming all the memory, maybe check (mscorsvw.exe)
2. It could be SQL Mgmt Studio, in which you would need to uninstall it and then re-install. Check to see after you uninstall it that you still get the same error message.
3. It could be what a lot of posts online talk about a software hive corruption. Which a lot have resolved the problem with restoring the software hive. I think you can restore a copy of the file from "%windir%\system32\config\regback" to "%windir%\system32\config"
4. Maybe this, I don't think its this, but this info might help troubleshoot - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002606
5. I am leaning towards this resolution the most as I mentioned in number 3 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304101

I hope something here helps you out.