# Eclipse (STS) started getting CreateProcess error=1450, Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Been using this Eclipse workspace for a long time (5 months to be exact), but just today this error started occuring.
It occurs even for a simple Java main which just outputs a string.
I've restarted my PC and even [tried the steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19845580/system-error-1450-has-occurred-insufficient-system-resources-exist-to-complete) here again restarted but still getting this **"CreateProcess error=1450, Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service".**

Has anyone encountered this and how did you fix it?

### Heading ##[image]

Answer (score 0):

Really unsure what happened, but for the meantime, I replaced the jdk-10 folder with a freshly downloaded jdk 10 from Oracle.
One thing I did notice is that the old jdk-10 was:
[image]

Wheres the fresh download was:
[image]

I still don't understand why it worked for 5 months and only today that it became broken...